# Syncfusion_Flutter_Pdf: Make objects appear on the same page

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

I'm trying to create a pdf file. I've created two separate files in the document. That is a String and a Table.
However, the two objects are in separate pages. How do I bring them to be on one page?

```
Future<void> printCustomersPdf(
    transactions,
    date,
    amountInSymbol,
  ) async {
    PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
    final page = document.pages.add();
    /*First object*/
    page.graphics
        .drawString("HitchRide", PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.courier, 30));
    /*Second object*/
    PdfGrid grid = PdfGrid();
    grid.columns.add(count: 2);
    grid.headers.add(1);

    PdfGridRow header = grid.headers[0];
    header.cells[0].value = date;
    header.cells[1].value = amountInSymbol;
    header.style = PdfGridCellStyle(
      backgroundBrush: PdfBrushes.lightGray,
      textBrush: PdfBrushes.black,
      font: PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.timesRoman, 12),
    );

    for (final customer in transactions) {
      PdfGridRow row = grid.rows.add();
      row.cells[0].value = customer.date;
      row.cells[1].value = "${customer.amount}.00";
    }
    grid.style = PdfGridStyle(
      cellPadding: PdfPaddings(left: 10, right: 3, top: 4, bottom: 5),
      backgroundBrush: PdfBrushes.white,
      textBrush: PdfBrushes.black,
      font: PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.timesRoman, 12),
    );
    grid.draw(
        page: document.pages.add(), bounds: const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 0, 0));
    List<int> bytes = await document.save();
    AnchorElement(
        href:
            "data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,${base64.encode(bytes)}")
      ..setAttribute("download", "report.pdf")
      ..click();
    document.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: What would you recommens?

Comment: package:pdf seems quite popular and full-featured.

Comment: The problem is I'm finding it difficult implementing it. Could you help?

Comment: In my experience, PDF in general is difficult.  It's a very complex standard, essentially standardizing what people were doing with PostScript.

Answer (score 0):

The PdfTextElement provides the layout result of the added text by using the location of the next element to prevent content overlapping. Finally, the text string is added, followed by the grid table. We have adjusted the code accordingly and included a snippet for your reference.

```
    PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();

  PdfPage page = document.pages.add();

  /*First object*/

  PdfTextElement textElement=PdfTextElement(text: 'HitchRide',font: PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.courier,30));

  PdfLayoutFormat layoutFormat = PdfLayoutFormat(

  layoutType: PdfLayoutType.paginate,

  breakType: PdfLayoutBreakType.fitPage);

  PdfLayoutResult result=textElement.draw(page: page,bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, page.getClientSize().width / 2, page.getClientSize().height),format: layoutFormat)!;

  /*Second object*/

  PdfGrid grid = PdfGrid();

  grid.columns.add(count: 2);

  grid.headers.add(1);

  PdfGridRow header = grid.headers[0];

  header.cells[0].value = "date";

  header.cells[1].value = "amountInSymbol";

  header.style = PdfGridCellStyle(

    backgroundBrush: PdfBrushes.lightGray,

    textBrush: PdfBrushes.black,

    font: PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.timesRoman, 12),

  );

  

    PdfGridRow row = grid.rows.add();

    row.cells[0].value = "customerdate";

    row.cells[1].value = "300";

  

  grid.style = PdfGridStyle(

    cellPadding: PdfPaddings(left: 10, right: 3, top: 4, bottom: 5),

    backgroundBrush: PdfBrushes.white,

    textBrush: PdfBrushes.black,

    font: PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.timesRoman, 12),

  );

  grid.draw(page: result.page, bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(0,result.bounds.bottom+10, result.page.getClientSize().width, result.page.getClientSize().height-result.bounds.bottom+10));

  //Save and dispose the document.

  List<int> bytes = await document.save();

  AnchorElement(

      href:

          "data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,${base64.encode(bytes)}")

    ..setAttribute("download", "report.pdf")

    ..click();

  document.dispose();
```

Note:
I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).